# Kafka Stream: How to trigger event based on hopping windows and how to trigger event based on combined set of windows that are part of hopping window

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Here is our topology:

test-events--->groupByKey-->Window Aggregation-->Suppress-->Filter-->rekey

Here is the flow

We have 1 min hopping window.  With total window size of 5 min.  The hopping window is evaluated every five minutes, HOW to get count of every 1 min hops??

Total 5 min window, hop duration 1 min.

```
1. How to TRIGGER some event based on 1 min HOP

2. How to TRIGGER some event based on TOTAL 5 min WINDOW


   ||-----||----||-------||------||-----|

          ||-----||----||-------||------||-----|
```

We want to do 2 things.

1. We want to count total number of events in a hopping window of 1 min.  If total number of events are  > some threshold then trigger one combined event for that 1 min hopping window.
2. Then we want to trigger an alert if count of combined event is > some number.

From Kafka window API

```
Code looks like this:
KStream<String, DataPointUri> KS0 = builder.stream(inputTopicsList,);
KGroupedStream<String, DataPointUri> KS1 = KS0.groupByKey();
Duration windowDuration =getDuration(...)); 
Duration hopDuration =getDuration(env.getProperty(...)));
TimeWindowedKStream<String, DataPointUri> KS2 = KS1.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowDuration).advanceBy(hopDuration).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(10)));
KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> uriCount = KS2.count(Materialized.<String, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Here we are getting count for 5 min window.  NOT for hop 1 min window.  How to get details of 1 min window?